# Paste from clipboard works for some people and not for others

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am working on a file which allows users to select Region (from drop-down list), and around 40 check-boxes to choose if they want them to be included in the email list. After the selection is made, "Distribution List" button - which opens up a userform with one button "Copy to Clipboard". When user opens new email and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> it pastes the chosen checkboxes as the "To" address.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    With New DataObject
        .SetText Range("C4").Text ' Cell C4 has formula - CONCATENATE($G$11,$G$8,$G$17,$G$22,$G$26,$G$41,$G$56,$G$61,$G$70)
        .PutInClipboard
    End With
    Unload userForm1
    MsgBox "E-mail list copied successfully!"
End Sub
```

The macro runs on my system. It works for some people and for others when they hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> into the "To:" address they get nothing.

Comment: Anecdotally - lately I find the `DataObject` is pretty unreliable method for working with the clipboard.  Windows API (assuming you don't need to support Mac) is more robust.

Comment: Thank you so much, @TimWilliams.